# Finding probabilities of a continuous random variable

Tags: probability, integration, functions, probability-distributions, graphing-functions

I have the following continuous random variable density function:

$$ f(x) =
\begin{cases}
\frac14 & if\,0\le x<1 \\
\frac12 & if\,1\le x<2 \\
a & if\,2\le x<4 \\
0 & \text{the rest}
\end{cases}$$

Finding $a$: $$\int_{-\infty}^\infty{f(x)dx}=1 \Rightarrow a=\frac18$$

I am aware that: $$\frac{dF(x)}{dx}=f(x)$$ And thus: $$\int_a^b{f(x)dx}=F(x)+C$$

The graph for $f(x)$ is quite easy. I will upload it when needed or when I find some easy way how to plot here.

I need to find the distribution function $F(x)$ and its graph.

I can do the integrating on the cases in the $f(x)$ and the plotting too with some help of i.e. calculator TABLE function, but I have no idea how to get the integration constant $C$ there. Please help me. Thank You!

Side note: I do not need the definitive answer, but at least please show me the way.

**EDIT**

The answer has been found in the comments, with the help of [André Nicolas](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/6312/andr%C3%A9-nicolas)

$$ F(x) =
\begin{cases}
0 & if\,x<0 \\
\frac14 x & if\,0\le x<1 \\
\frac12 x-\frac14 & if\,1\le x<2 \\
\frac18 x+\frac12 & if\,2\le x<4 \\
1 & if\,x\ge 4
\end{cases}$$

Lets say, for the interval of $2\le x<4$ the calculation is $F(x)=\int_0^1\frac14 dx+\int_1^2\frac12 dx+\int_2^x\frac18 dx$

Now the new question is, how to plot easily this two graphs **in PC** (so they can be put here for the future reference)?

**EDIT 2**

There is one more task associated with this question - to calculate probabilities. Here they are with the answers.

$$P(X<1)=\frac56;\,P(X>-0.5)=\frac{11}{12};\,P(|X|<0.3)=0.3350$$

Now again, I am aware of the formulas for probabilities:

$$P(X<a)=\int_{-\infty}^a f(t)dt$$
$$P(X>b)=\int_b^\infty f(t)dt = 1-F(b)$$

But whatever I put into them, the desired numbers just wont get out. Could you please help me figure out the steps that leads to the given probabilities? Thank You!

Comment: Forget about integration constants, we are doing definite integrals. Actually, you can also forget about integrations, since we are finding areas of rectangles. But I will use integration notation. Clearly we have $F(x)=0$ if $x\lt 0$. For $0\le x\lt 1$, we have $F(x)=\int_0^x \frac{1}{4}\,dt$. For $1\le x\lt 2$ we have $F(x)=\int_0^1 \frac{1}{4}\,dt+\int_1^x \frac{1}{2}\,dt$. And so on.

Comment: @AndréNicolas the cumulative part now makes sense for me. But the presentations still show the $C$ there with fancy numbers that I cannot wrap my head around. I believe, there has to be something underlying them.

Comment: I have to guess what you might be referring to. Let me do the second part in that style. For $1\le x\lt 2$, we have $F(x)=\frac{1}{2}x+C$ for some $C$. But (from earlier part of the calculation) we have $F(1)=\frac{1}{4}$. So $C=-\frac{1}{4}$ and for $1\le x\lt 2$ we have $F(x)=\frac{1}{2}x-\frac{1}{4}$.

Comment: Then the presentations are wrong if there's a +c for a definite integral

Comment: @AndréNicolas Here is the [presentation](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B_XC5xRThT1qaUF4UkVIeEJGbVU/view?usp=sharing) see pages 22 and 23 please, if you mind. The $C$ there is $\frac12$ and then $3.5$

Comment: It looks like a different  example, though the same ideas come up.  (I can read it easily).  Note that the methods in my two comments yield the same answer. I prefer the first approach, it seems a little more concrete.

Comment: @AndréNicolas I can see it now. Using the first method, the third one would be $F(x)=\int_0^1\frac14 dx+\int_1^2\frac12 dx+\int_2^x\frac18 dx$ for $2\le x<4$ which is $\frac{x}{8}+\frac12$, right? Let me see if I can move further.

Comment: It is right. As a check, note that it is $3/4$ at $2$ and $1$ at $4$, which is what it should be. Also, it is linear in between, and $x/8 +1/2$ is the only linear thing that gives the right answer at the two endpoints.

Comment: You are welcome.  The graph is easy to draw with minimal computation. It is piecewise linear. Don't forget to write $F(x)=1$ if $x\ge 1$, and $F(x)=0$ for $x\lt 0$. For the cumulative distribution function is defined for all real $x$. Doing a few of this type of problem is important, for it helps develop intuition about what cumulative distribution function **means**.

Comment: @AndréNicolas I have plotted the graph by hand, in my notes. As you said it is easy and all linear, no problem. Just do not know the quick method here, in computer, you know?

Comment: Because it is piecewise linear, all we need to know is $F(0)=0$, $F(1)=1/4$, $F(2)=3/4$, $F(1)=1$. So for the important part of the cdf, join $(0,0)$ to $(1,1/4)$. Join $(1,1/4)$ to $2,3/4)$. Join $(2,3/4)$ to $(4,1)$. But this quick method only works for piecewise linear cdf, which are scarce in the real world.

Comment: @AndréNicolas Please, I have one more question on this topic, I have added a second EDIT. Maybe you could look at if, if you had some time. Thank you anyway!

Comment: I will not be able to do it for a while.  Unfortunately there are already a couple of close votes, and the question may be closed before I can get to it.   That may create a problem, since it is awkward to type math in comments.

Comment: It turns out the task is very easy, can be done quickly in a comment. The probability that $X\lt 1$ is clearly $1/4$. The "answer" $5/6$ is wrong. Even more clearly, $\Pr(X\gt -0.5)=1$. The "answer" $11/12$ is  wrong, I will not look at the others, the "answers" seem to be answers to a question about a random variable which has a different distribution than the one given at the beginning of the post.

Comment: @AndréNicolas Yes! That was the answers I was getting, I will write to the teacher, maybe he will clarify, but all the other 9 tasks there have good answers. Thank you!

Comment: You are welcome.